# Add breakpoint to Java library code in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am debugging an issue in my Spring application, but the issue is somewhere in the configuration in Spring. So I would like to add a breakpoint in one of the classes of Spring. Is it possible to do this in VS Code?

Comment: [This](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/09/28/java-debug) will help

Comment: I don't see how to add breakpoints to library code on that page. I have the `.java` files of my own project where I can set breakpoints. But I want to set a breakpoint in a class of the Spring Framework.

Answer (score 0):

The Java debugger also supports external source files.you could refer to [Debugging external files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_debugging-external-files)